# Loading a few data columns without loading the whole data first

Tags: r

I have high dimensional data and I do not want to load all columns at once as it blocks R and all ongoing processes on my computer.

To explore the data, I would like to first know the number of rows and columns, the names of the columns and if possible the variable types (i.e., character, factor, integer, numeric). And finally I would like to load only a few columns of this .csv file. I have seen examples but it seemed to me that still first the whole data was loaded and after that the desired columns were selected.

So my question is basically: Are these exploration- and selection steps possible in R without first loading the whole data at once?

Comment: `data.table::fread(file = "...", nrows = 10)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using {data.table}'s fread() for this kind of task, since it is the fastest package to work with files in R.
You can specify "nrows" to read the desired amount of rows, or nrows=0 to just read the header, for example

```
library(data.table)
fread("filename.csv",nrows=5)
```

You can also use "select" parameter to specify the columns that you want (either by name or by index), but that won't really speed up the process, because usually the file is read row-by-row, and reading lets say 1st, 3d and 5th column will be just as quick as all of them.